# Gradle test fixtures plugin and core module dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management, gradle-kotlin-dsl, java-test-fixtures

I have a project built with Gradle version 6.4 and JDK 8. I'm trying to use the Gradle [plugin for Test Fixtures](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:java_test_fixtures) (`java-test-fixtures`) but I have some issues with the dependencies.

According to the Gradle page linked above, the project should be structured like this:

```
core-module
-- src
   -- main
      -- java
   -- test
      -- java
   -- testFixtures
      -- java
```

While the `build.gradle.kts` file has the following dependencies section:

```kotlin
dependencies {
    api("com.my.external.project:1.0")
    // ... more API dependencies

    testFixturesCompileOnly(project(":core-module"))
    testFixturesApi("junit:junit:4.12")
    // ... more test dependencies
}
```

Now, in IntelliJ (the IDE I'm using) classes in the `testFixtures/java` source folder see the classes in the `main/java` source folder. So I can add new Java classes under `testFixtures/java` that have dependencies on those under `main`.
However, I won't be able to import the dependencies from the external library `com.my.external.project:1.0`. The problem is confirmed when I try to run the Gradle task `compileTestFixturesJava`.

I can duplicate the entry in the `dependencies` section; e.g. I can add:

```kotlin
testFixturesImplementationOnly("com.my.external.project:1.0")
```

But that is not really what I expect to do; especially when I have dozens of dependencies.

I could also define the dependencies in an array and run a `for-each` over them.  Still, this is not the cleanest solution.

Is there a clean solution that will allow the `testFixtures` module  to use the dependencies declared in the `main` module?

Comment: Any reason you're not just using a multiproject build?

Comment: This is how it is structured in my company and I can't change it.

Comment: @JeanValjean Correct me if my understand is wrong -- is the error here that the Gradle task `compileTestFixturesJava` fails without a duplicated entry because it (for whatever reason) is not drawing from the already-specified dependencies declared as `api`/`implementation` under the `dependencies` tag (available to `main`), causing unresolved classes? Also, would you be able to provide a minimalist reproduction repository?

Comment: I have the same problem, if you know how to solve it, please tell me how

Comment: @concision the answer to your first question is yes (if I get you right). For the second, I may not find the time. Let's see.

Comment: I created a simple project here https://github.com/mricciuti/so-64133013  but could not reproduce your issue:  in this example, `testFixture` classes  can see `main` dependencies (here :commons-lang3) :  if you analyse dependencies you will see that  `testFixturesCompileClasspath` inherits from `main` dependencies . maybe you could compare this simple project to yours and check what's different?

Comment: @M.Ricciuti class https://github.com/mricciuti/so-64133013/blob/master/core-module/src/testFixtures/java/com/acme/Simpsons.java in test fixtures is not using JUnit, for instance, nor any code from the main module

Comment: @JeanValjean  1) "classes in test fixtures is not using JUnit" :indeed, but they are  not supposed to! (and if you really need this, just add `junit` dependency in `testFixturesImplementation` configuration.   2) "nor any code from the main module" ==> you're wrong: `Simpsons` class in test Fixture references `Person` class from `main` sourcesSet..

Comment: @JeanValjean Are you satisfied with the solution already proposed in the comments? Am I correct in thinking it wouldn't be worth anybody else expending any more effort beyond that? To be honest, I'd be surprised if you received any *better* answers — if that's what you're holding out for.

Comment: @JeanValjean If you are able to provide a minimal reproduction, I can take a detailed look into this. I do not think I would be able to accurately guess your current build configuration.

Comment: @M.Ricciuti why do you say that they are not supposed to use dependencies from the test module? The Gradle page doesn't even says you have to add a dependency from the main module, as you did. For me there is no point in having a testFixtures folder under the another module if the plugin doesn't explicitly inherit from the main module. The fact I also have to import dependencies for testing explicitly for the fixtures folder is stupid, since most likely I will write utilities using JUnit, AssertJ and other testing tools.

Comment: @deduper no, I'm ok. Disappointed on how poor is the documentation for that plugin and  that it is not so flexible as it could.

Comment: @M.Ricciuti thanks for the POC and comment. You could turn it into an answer, so tha we can shape that fr future devs that will jump in here.

Comment: @JeanValjean you're right, it makes sense to have test framework dependencies in testFixtures scope (e.g. if you want to setup some shared mock instances using `mockito`), personally I use testFixtures only for setting up domain entity instances for test purpose, but your use case is perfectly valid. in this case, just declare your needed dependencies in `testFixturesImplementation` or `testFixturesApi` scope.  regarding dependency from `testFixture` to `main` sourceSet it's automatically set up by the plugin so you don't need to declare it : I did it just because I copied your initial example

Comment: I'll provide soon an answer with an enriched version of my previous POC, to show a valid example based on your last comment.  cheers

Comment: „*…how poor is the documentation for that plugin…*“ —  I agree. When I've been stumped by Gradle issues, somebody either [*in their forums*](https://discuss.gradle.org/latest) or [*on their Slack channel*](https://gradle-community.slack.com/) have rescued me. — „*…it is not so flexible as it could…*“ — I think that plugin's goal is to be X-Unit agnostic; to facilitate fixtures meant to be (*re*)used in different projects. One project might use TestNG. Another might use Spock, etc. If JUnit 5's *baked* into the testFixture then it probably wouldn't be as *portable* across different projects.

Comment: Have you tried this:
```sourceSets {
    testFixtures {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
    }
}``` (sorry for the bad formatting)

Comment: „*…Have you tried this: `sourceSets { … }`*“ – @blagerweij — Isn't that already being configured *implicitly* by [*`JavaPlugin.configureSourceSets(JavaPluginConvention, BuildOutputCleanupRegistry)`*](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaPlugin.java#L329) and [*`JavaTestFixturesPlugin.createImplicitTestFixturesDependencies(Project, JavaPluginConvention)`*](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaTestFixturesPlugin.java#L78)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Most important concept in the Gradle `java-test-fixtures` plugin is stated in their [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:java_test_fixtures):

> [this plugin] will automatically create a testFixtures source set, in which you can write your test fixtures. Test fixtures are configured so that:
>
> - they can see the main source set classes
> - test sources can see the test fixtures classes

This plugin will indeed create the following dependencies:   `main` <-- `testFixtures`  , and   `testFixtures` <-- `test`

In your case, `testFixtures` module should automatically depend on `main` sources, and also on `main` dependencies declared in `api` scope ( `com.my.extenal.project:1.0`)

See a similar example in a valid sample project here https://github.com/mricciuti/so-64133013 :

- [Simpsons](https://github.com/mricciuti/so-64133013/blob/master/core-module/src/testFixtures/java/com/acme/Simpsons.java) class has access to `Person` class from main module
- [TestHelpers](https://github.com/mricciuti/so-64133013/blob/master/core-module/src/testFixtures/java/com/acme/TestHelpers.java) class has access to `main` dependencies declared in `api` configuration

Note that `testFixtures` will not inherit dependencies from the `test` module: if you need to use such libraries in this module (eg. JUnit, Mockito, ...) you will need to declare explicit dependency , using  `testFixturesImplementation` or `testFixturesApi` configuration.

See example in [`core-module`](https://github.com/mricciuti/so-64133013/blob/master/core-module/build.gradle.kts)

```
plugins {
    id ("java-library")
    id ("java-test-fixtures")
}
dependencies {
    // Main dependencies
    //   will be available in "testFixture" as well thanks to "api" configuration
    api("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9")
    api(project(":utils-module"))

    // Testfixture dependencies
        // ==> mockito lib will be available in testFixture module and also in consumer modules (e.g test)
    testFixturesApi("org.mockito:mockito-core:3.5.13")

    // Test dependencies
       // dependencies specific to the "test" module; not visible from "testFixtures"
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1")
    testRuntimeOnly ("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1")
}
```

Comment: It was `testFixturesApi(project(":utils-module"))` that saved the day for me